# Struct with scanf and file

Tags: c, file, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    struct data {
        char *first;
        char *last;
        int age;
        char *email;
        int bday[3];
    };

typedef struct data id;


void id_read(){
        FILE *fp;
```

Creates file for the purpose

```
        fp=fopen("Data.txt" , "w");
```

Reads the data and prints them in the File

```
        printf("Give First name please: ");
             scanf("%s" , &(id.first));
        fprintf( fp , "First name: %s" , id.first);
        printf("\nGive Last name please: ");
             scanf("%s" , &(id.last));
        fprintf(fp ,"\nLast name: %s" , id.last);
        printf("\nGive your email: ");
             scanf("%s" , &(id.email));
        fprintf(fp , "\nEmail: %s" , id.email);
        printf("\nGive birthday date: ");
        printf("\nDay: ");
             scanf("%d" , &id.bday[0]);
        printf("\nMonth: ");
             scanf("%d" , &(id.bday[1]));
        printf("\nYear: ");
             scanf("%d" , &(id.bday[2]));
        fprintf(fp ,"\nBirthdate: %d/%d/%d" , id.bday[0] , id.bday[1] , id.bday[2]);
        printf("\nGive your age: ");
             scanf("%d", &(id.age));
        fprintf(fp , "\nAge: %d" , id.age);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

main fuction

```
 int main(){
        printf("Give your ID carefully! \n\n");
        id_read();
        return 0;
 }
```

Compiler errors with scanf.

```
 [Error] expected expression before ')' token.
 [Error] expected ')' before '.' token
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

`id` is a typedef data type, not a variable itself. Need to have a variable of type `id`, say, `id input`. Then,

1. Need to allocate memory to the pointer `input.first` using `malloc()`.
2. `scanf("%s" , &(id.first));` needs to be changed to `scanf("%s" , input.first);`

same for other pointer variables.

Comment: I corrected this and the programm works fine until the point where the email has to be scaned. Then the programm crashes! Do you have any idea why is this happening? Thank you very much!

Comment: You allocated memory? Of what size? Memory should be large enough to hold a large email id, say `thisisanexampleoflargeemailid@verylargeemailidprovider.co.in`.

Comment: I have to do this even if i am using a pointer for the string? Why doesn't this happening for first or last?

Comment: @konstantinos yes. Without allocating memory, how you can store something into it?

Comment: I store first and last with pointers without allocating memory

Comment: @Konstantinos Tsirakos When you break the rules _sometimes_ you do not get caught.  Follow the rules (C spec) and allocate memory and code will work.